# is there any way to store all transactions ever made by a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, transactions

this is more an informative question. I'm developing an app for a book store and i want to store all transactions (Create, Read, Update, Delete) made to the DB (MongoDB). This information will be important to future machine learning process, AI, and so forth. So basically i want to know the best way to store all this transaction history in my DB. if you guys know any existing npm module, or standard that could help me it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongo auditing feature:

```
mongod --dbpath data/db --auditDestination file --auditFormat JSON --auditPath data/db/auditLog.json
```

This command will produce a json file in `data/db/` named `auditLog.json`

you can read the documentations about it here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-auditing/